# INSERT Data from textbox in WPF to SQL table with a button click

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I have a WPF app with multiple windows. One of my windows contains a TextBox named startText. I also have a button named SubmitButton. I've created a SQL database and through the wizard and it has connected my app through the app.config. I want to convert the text that is typed into the textbox into a variable and insert that into a new row on one of my tables of the database. The database only has one column named Story the datbases name is Story as well ([Story].[dbo].[Story]). I am new the c# and not sure where an INSERT statement goes in my go.
Here is my App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="StoryTest.Properties.Settings.StoryConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=STORY\STORY;Initial Catalog=Story;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Here is my WPF app config:

```
 public partial class StartAStory : Window
    {



private  object Story;public StartAStory()

        {

            InitializeComponent();
            SubmitButton.Click += SubmitButton_Click;
            startText.Copy();

        }

        void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection();
            Conn.Open();

        }
        private void SetToClipBoard(object text)
        {
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(text);
        }
        private void PasteData()
        {
            IDataObject ClipData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

            if (ClipData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            {
                string s = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

I know I'm missing a few things here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a lot of things for a 'new to C#' dev to tackle here.

So looks to me like your going with code behind, the .cs file that sits with your window. In here you can create an event handler for your button to do all this saving to database but you first need to get the value from the text box.

In your xaml, make sure your text box has a name. I shall assume it is called myTextbox.

In your code behind, you should then be able to access the text box control using this.myTextbox. To get your input value, this.myTextbox.Text.

With the text value, you are going to want to now insert that into your database.

The preferred way is to create an entity framework model of your database which gives you a whole object model to play with. Instead, you look to be wanting to talk directly to you db with SQL. In that case, lookup SqlCommand using parameters, to protect yourself from SQL injection. [example here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06).

Once you've got to terms with that, definitely look at Entity Framework, and build on your WPF by implementing a Viewmodel since we tend to avoid code behind unless it is purely for the visual.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Forgot to say, adding an event handler is easier in the xaml designer, select you control and the top right of the properties panel has a lightning bolt icon. Click that to see a list of supported events for your button, double click the one you want to create the handler in your code behind.